# A doubt on uniform limit of a sequence of uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, sequence-of-function

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872099/convergence-of-uniformly-continous-functions-to-a-uniformly-continous-function) is MSE.

Suppose $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of uniformly continous functions and $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

These are the questions that I put myself.

1. What can I say about the **uniform continuity** of the uniform limit $f$ ?
2. Suppose that the uniform limit function $f$ is also uniformly continuous. Will the result hold good if I change the domain to $\mathbb{R}$ or any other subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R},$ which is not necessarily compact ?

**My attempt:**

1. Given that $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of uniformly continous functions. Then for every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists a $\delta_n(\epsilon)>0,$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta_n, $ with $x,y \in [0,1].$

Since, $f$ is the uniform limit of the sequence $f_n,$ for the same $\epsilon>0,$ that we took previously, there exists a natural number $N(\epsilon),$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$ whenever  $n>N(\epsilon).$

Now, choose $\delta_1=max\{\delta_n,\delta\}.$

Then, we have that $|f(x)-f(y)|= |f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(y)+f_n(y)-f(y)| \le |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|=\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon,$ for any $x,y \in [0,1]$ such that $|x-y|<\delta_1.$
So, the uniform limit $f$ is also uniformly continuous.

Is this proof correct? Or have I made any mistakes. If yes, please point it out. This shall benefit me immensly.

As for the part 2), I feel like the same logic works well for any arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ also. I am not able to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: If the result is not true for arbitrary sets, then please provide me with a counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: It's true for arbitrary sets.

Comment: @Ricky Does the same proof hold good ?

Comment: The result is true for real functions on any metric space.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602258/is-the-uniform-limit-of-uniformly-continuous-functions-uniformly-continuous-its